# jQuery $(this).children not working?

Tags: jquery

I'm sure jQuery works fine, but for some reason it isn't for me. I can't even put it into a jsFiddle because it doesn't like Ajax, but my statements involving `$(this).children` are not working at all. I'm not getting any errors... what am I doing wrong?

**JS**

```
$('.submitNewOrder').submit( function() {
    $(this).children('input[type=\"submit\"]').prop('disabled',true); // Doesn't work
    $(this).children('.saving').fadeIn('fast');  // Doesn't work
    $.ajax({
        url: 'scripts/submitNewOrder.php?catID=1',
        data: newOrder,
        type: 'POST',
        mode: 'abort',
        success: function(){
            $(this).children('.saving').fadeOut('fast', function() { // Doesn't work
                $(this).children('.success').fadeIn('fast'); // Doesn't work
            });
        },
        error: function(){
            $(this).children('.error').fadeIn('fast'); // Doesn't work
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form class="submitNewOrder">
    <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Save order" />
        <span class="saving" style="display:none">Saving changes...</span>
        <span class="success" style="display:none">Saved!</span>
        <span class="error" style="display:none">There was a problem saving :(</span>
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you aware `.children()` returns only direct children? Also, have you checked what `this` refers to in ajax callbacks? Why haven't you?

Comment: Try this $(this).children.find('.saving').fadeOut('fast', function() {
                $(this).children.find('.success').fadeIn('fast');
            });

Comment: @Django Reinhardt: "If I know this was the issue, I wouldn't have to post the question" --- isn't it the first thing to check? I always check **every** variable has the expected value before trying to go deeper (asking on SO, or filing a bug ticket). #protip: don't believe yourself and always check everything: as a programmer you should follow the facts, not belief and expectations.

Comment: This works - http://jsfiddle.net/PzJbd/1/

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt always store `this` is another variable if you're not going to use it immediately (storing `$(this)` for later use is even better)

Comment: @mpapec maybe, but here ajax has an option to proxify the context, the well named 'context' option.

Comment: @roasted yes, but I'm not sure that such advice is good for someone who struggles with variable scoping

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try replacing the `children` with `find` like:

```
$('.submitNewOrder').submit(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.find('input[type=\"submit\"]').prop('disabled', true); 
    $this.find('.saving').fadeIn('fast'); 
    $.ajax({
        url: 'scripts/submitNewOrder.php?catID=1',
        data: newOrder,
        type: 'POST',
        mode: 'abort',
        success: function () {
            $this.find('.saving').fadeOut('fast', function () { 
                $this.find('.success').fadeIn('fast'); 
            });
        },
        error: function () {
            $this.find('.error').fadeIn('fast'); 
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I'd forgotten about `this` and Ajax and misread the PHP documentation. Double doh.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt you mean jQuery Documentation i think

Comment: @roasted Yes, I certainly do.

Answer (score 3):

Use context option of ajax and use `.find()` instead of `.children()`:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'scripts/submitNewOrder.php?catID=1',
        data: newOrder,
        type: 'POST',
        mode: 'abort',
        context: this, //<< HERE so in callback functions, 'this' refers to the object, not options object of ajax call
        success: function(){
            $(this).find('.saving').fadeOut('fast', function() {
                $(this).find('.success').fadeIn('fast');
            });
        },
        error: function(){
            $(this).find('.error').fadeIn('fast');
        }
    });
```

Comment: You'll note that NONE of my references to `$(this).children()` are working, including the ones outside of the Ajax call.

Comment: @Django Reinhardt: have you read documentation about `.children()` method? Why haven't you? Why do you think it works as you think if you haven't read the documentation? http://api.jquery.com/children/ PS: if the issue is irrelevant to ajax - you could remove ajax part from your code in the question to not confuse answerers.

Comment: @roasted: "should be children('input[type=submit]')" --- actually his selector is correct. And it's recommended to enclose attribute values in quotes

Comment: @zerkms I love how you're preaching that people should read and check every little thing before posting, but then post comments that indicate you haven't read the question properly. Nice.

Comment: @Django Reinhardt: 1. I didn't answer the question 2. The complete answer to your question is in my first comment (it both explains your fail about `.children()` and `this` value in the callbacks). I realize that you came here to get a complete solution to your problem, not just a hints. Eating free fish is better than fishing indeed.

Comment: @zerkms Once it was edited, yes. It's very easy to sit and point out other people's flaws and mistakes. I guess it makes you feel like a big man. Once again, it's people like you that give SO its terrible reputation.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt ya next time read comments too... And sorry for the wrong answer, too many things were wrong in your code... Next time i'll just not read your question, my apologies sincerely.

Comment: @Django Reinhardt: sorry for not answering your question in the way you like.

Comment: @zerkms Perhaps be mindful of people's feelings before you post something patronizing in the future.

Comment: @Django Reinhardt: the thing is - you could solve your issue *yourself* if you read my first comment (and followed documentation), not started being offended. But instead of that you decided to argue about the way I'm commenting and waiting for detailed answers.

Comment: @zerkms You can't be offensive to people and not expect them to be offended. Take responsibility for your actions. I'm completely aware that you were right and I'm not arguing that. I'm informing you of your horrible tone. I HAD read the documentation but, guess what, I misread it. I made a mistake. Every question on a Q&A site depends on the poster not knowing as much as the answerer -- due to ignorance, inexperience, or some other valid reason. Knowing more than the other person doesn't give anyone the right to patronize them.

Comment: @Django Reinhardt: tbh I don't see anything offensive in my first comment :-S

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt keep it jazzy, there is no problem here, you just make tone of nothing

Comment: @zerkms Maybe you need to learn a bit more about how to address people, then. Your comment was the very definition of patronizing.

Comment: @Django Reinhardt: I don't see why it's bad though

Comment: @zerkms You assumed I hadn't done any of the obvious things in your list, when actually I had tried both before posting. You didn't ASK if I'd tried those things, you actually went ahead and assumed it, even going so far as to end your comment with the extremely pointed sentence. "Why haven't you?" That's insulting and patronizing. If we cross paths on this site again, do not talk to me like that.

Comment: @Django Reinhardt: ""Why haven't you?" That's insulting and patronizing" --- well, that's expected question. Now you will check everything before asking, won't you? So I was useful, wasn't I? ;-)

Comment: @roasted You didn't answer my question. That's what downvoting is for. Now YOU'RE offended...?

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt ya you are right concerning valid HTML, input has inline-block as display by default, sorry.

Comment: @Django Reinhardt: I prefer to talk to intelligent and well educated people in real life, who don't punch after they got a free lesson (in the internet it's a bit more complicated to see who is who). So that's not the case.

Comment: @zerkms Intelligent, well educated people, understand when what they're saying is inappropriate. Again, take responsibility for your actions.

Comment: @Django Reinhardt: I don't have enough experience talking to over-sensitive men. Again I don't see anything wrong in my actions.

Comment: @zerkms Riiiight. Nice to see we're drifting into insults. Sorry, I guess you don't appreciate "free lessons" when they're directed at you (only when you're giving them?). Maybe in the future you'll think twice before posting something in the future. Isn't that useful?

Comment: Couldn't I have a badge for all the comments in my answer? :)

Comment: @Django Reinhardt: I didn't request for a free lessons for internet etiquette. So I don't appreciate that, that's correct. May be in the future I will do whatever I want, would you allow me that please?

Comment: @roasted: what's happened to the "move this conversation to chat" feature?! It would be useful here.

Comment: @roasted I don't know. I keep expecting it to kick in :-/

Comment: @zerkms Again, if you insult someone, expect them to be offended. You're an adult. You can do what you want, but you can't be surprised, or cry foul, if someone gets offended.

Comment: A beer for all of us, that's what we need

Comment: @Django Reinhardt: I didn't insult. I just asked what is the real reason for you to believe that your variable has the data you're expecting. For me, as a developer, it's obvious to check everything. Sorry for having too high demands for an average programmer.

Comment: @roasted: a beer and boxing gloves for me!

Comment: @zerkms Again with the insults, and you keep ignoring the fact: I *did* check everything before I posted, I just misread the documentation. Just because I made a mistake doesn't mean you get to be insulting. If someone was offended by what you said, then you were offensive. That's a plain fact. If you don't enjoy these conversations, I'd suggest changing how you address people in the future.

Comment: @Django Reinhardt: "I did check everything before I posted" --- you didn't. Otherwise you would ask "why `this` in callback stores not what I want".

Comment: @zerkms I checked the contents of `this` (but before the Ajax call) and read the documentation for `children()`. Again, just because I was wrong doesn't give you the right to be insulting. Again, you have to take responsibility for your actions.

Comment: @Django Reinhardt: I didn't mean to be insulting. It's you who just insulted on a neutral phrase.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt One thing, it's best if you put in the question that you already tested certain scenarios(describing them) and you are still confused. This way people will not jump to the conclusion that you may have missed something obvious. Let's face it most jQuery questions are obvious and I think that has made many people jaded, including me :)

Comment: @Liviu T: hey! Do you personally think I was rude to Django? ;-)

Comment: @zerkms Ok, it's becoming more and more apparent that your grasp on the English language isn't the best, and that it isn't your first language. Given this fact, I'd seriously consider taking the advice of a native speaker: What you wrote was patronizing. You may not have meant it that way, but that's how it read.

Comment: @Django Reinhardt: I don't see how "patronizing" is a bad thing. You came here to be learned. So just accept that not every teaching methodology is the one you expect it to be (especially keeping in mind it's a free and open community).

Comment: @zerkms Trust me, "patronizing" is a bad thing. If you're patronizing to people, they will be offended. It's your choice.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/32749/jquery-this-children-not-working?tab=general Here you go guys.

Comment: @Liviu T.: you didn't answer! :-) Do you think I was rude? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In `submit` `this` points to the `form` element. The elements you are looking for are not children of `form`, but children of `<p>`. Change your expressions to `$(this).find(...)`, which will search further than one level down the tree.